# Invalid template file: 'Magento_Review::helper/summary_short.phtml

Tags: magento2, review

We are using magento2.3
How i can fix this error?

below is **system.log** error stack:

```
[2019-03-25 01:00:40] main.ERROR: Environment emulation nesting is not allowed. [] []
[2019-03-25 01:00:40] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'Magento_Review::helper/summary_short.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Review' block's name: '' [] []
```

We are not usig any custom module.

Comment: Please can you Provide your code.

Comment: you have custom calling this file? also check `Magento_Review` is 1 in `app/etc/config.php` file

Comment: not to my knowledge. Is there way to check that?  'Magento_Review' => 1, is on

Comment: yes you can check this extension enable or not

Answer (score 1):

Your code is looks like

```
<?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType, true); ?>
```

Please Replace a Code With it

```
<?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType); ?>
```

It's Working for me.

edit:added echo

Comment: https://prnt.sc/n2kwhk this is the only one place on the website where short summary is injected. We are not using reviews with custom blocks.

Comment: Please Provide your code When File is called , xml Or Phtml ??

Comment: code: <?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType, true); ?>

Comment: When i remove "true" at the end, the reviews summary are not showing.

Comment: It is Working ??

Comment: https://prnt.sc/n2mul4   https://prnt.sc/n2muyg   Please see the printscreens. Unfortunately  its not working after i remove true at the end rating stars are not there anymore.

Comment: if you have fixed this error,please update the code.

Comment: This solution is not working for me.I checked the logs today and the same error still persist. Thanks anyways.