# Upgrading to Magento 2.4.4 error on all product pages with reviews

Tags: magento2, product-review, magento2.4.4, magentomodule

I have been upgrading a magento store from 2.3.7 to 2.4.4 and facing the error below on any product page which has reviews. I saw a similar error in another post and did serialize the rating as suggested there but it made no difference.

Thanks for all the help.

````
    {
        "*": {
                "Magento_Catalog/js/product/view/provider": {
                    "data":             <span class="reviewrate">TypeError: Unsupported operand types: Magento\Framework\DataObject / int in /home/livinghabitat/public_html/app/design/frontend/Rsg/kairali/Magento_Review/templates/helper/summary_short.phtml:14```
````

Comment: Are you running PHP 8?

Comment: Paste code in app/design/frontend/Rsg/kairali/Magento_Review/templates/helper/summary_short.phtml file

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @MagePalExtensions yes I am running PHP 8.

Comment: @AlanZavagli I was posting the entire error but it kept marking the question as spam and so have only shared the first line.

Comment: @RaulSanchez summary_short.phtml is a default file in a magento 2 module module-review. I saw this post which asked to add serialize() to the get->ratings code which I followed but it did not fix my issue. ( https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/267222/invalid-template-file-magento-reviewhelper-summary-short-phtml )

Comment: @AlanZavagli you can see the full error on the site. [link](https://www.livinghabitat.in/kairtis-ayurvedic-pain-relief-oil-for-arthritis-and-spondylosis.html)